# I have having following warning in gcc compilation in 32 bit architecture but not having any such warning in 64 bit architecture

Tags: 32bit-64bit, gcc-warning

symbol.c: In function 'symbol_FPrint':

```
symbol.c:1209: warning: format '%ld' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'SYMBOL'
symbol.c: In function 'symbol_FPrintOtter':
symbol.c:1236: warning: format '%ld' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'SYMBOL'
symbol.c:1239: warning: format '%ld' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'SYMBOL'
symbol.c:1243: warning: format '%ld' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'SYMBOL'
symbol.c:1266: warning: format '%ld' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'SYMBOL'
```

In symbol.c

```
1198 #ifdef CHECK
1199     else {
1200       misc_StartErrorReport();
1201       misc_ErrorReport("\n In symbol_FPrint: Cannot print symbol.\n");
1202       misc_FinishErrorReport();
1203     }
1204 #endif
1205   }
1206   else if (symbol_SignatureExists())
1207     fputs(symbol_Name(Symbol), File);
1208   else
1209     fprintf(File, "%ld", Symbol);
1210 }
```

And SYMBOL is defined as:

```
typedef size_t SYMBOL
```

When i replaced '%ld' with '%zu' , i got the following warning:

```
symbol.c: In function 'symbol_FPrint':
symbol.c:1209: warning: ISO C90 does not support the 'z' printf length modifier
```

Note: From here it has been edited on 26th of march 2010 and and following problem has beeen added because of its similarity to the above mentioned problem.

I have following statement:

```
printf("\n\t %4d:%4d:%4d:%4d:%4d:%s:%d", Index, S->info, S->weight,
       Precedence[Index],S->props,S->name, S->length);
```

The warning I get while compiling in 64 bit architecture is :

```
format ‘%4d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘size_t’
```

here are the definitions of parameter:

```
  NAT    props;
  typedef  unsigned int     NAT;
```

How can i get rid of this so that i can compile without warning in 32 and 64 bit architecture?

What can be its solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%zu` rather than `%ld` as the format for `size_t` and then you'll get correct behaviour (and no warnings) in both 32-bit and 64-bit builds.

If for some reason you can't use `%zu` (e.g. old or non-standard compiler), then you can do something like this:

```
#ifdef __LP64__ // if 64 bit environment
#define FMT_SIZE_T "llu"
#else
#define FMT_SIZE_T "lu"
#endif
```

Then when you need to use printf with somethign of type size_t you can do this:

```
printf("(sizeof(void *) = %"FMT_SIZE_T" bytes \n", sizeof(void *));
```

Comment: that really worked for both , i got one more new warning on the same linei'e

ISO C90 does not support 'z' gnu_printf length modifier.

What can be the alternatives in this case?

Comment: Either use -std=c99 when you compile, or else #define a format specifier, e.g. `FMT_SIZE_T` which is #defined as `%llu` on 64-bit and `%lu` on 32-bit builds.

Comment: is it possible to remove such warning without relying into C99 standard?

Comment: @thetna: yes, as I said, you can just conditionally `#define` your own `FMT_SIZE_T` which is e.g. `%lu` for for 32-bit builds and `%llu` for 64-bit builds

Comment: @pual thanks for the reply. this can be again a stupid question but i am newbie to C.Does this changes make a single package compatible to both the architecture environement or need  to define spearately %lu for 32 bit and 64 bit architecture?

Comment: @thetna: I'll add an example to my answer which should hopefully make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

i find `%lu` to be the only C89-compliant (or, gcc-c89-warnings-compliant) format for `size_t`, on linux. under glibc, `size_t` seems to always be `long unsigned int`, so `%lu` is appropriate there.

in particular i found that gcc-4.4.3 with `-std=c89 -pedantic` or `-std=c89 -Wall` will warn about `%llu` and `%lld`. makes sense, since they expect `long long`, a C99 type.

tragically there isn't a way to print a `size_t` in a platform-independent C89-compliant way. in C89, **all** `printf` formats refer to specific primitive types (`long`, `int`, etc), but in **all** C dialects, `size_t` is platform-dependent (might be `long` or `int` or something else).

as usual, microsoft throws you its own special monkey wrench. the windows compilation environment is a badly-modified C89: it has `long long`, but no `ll` printf modifier. in windows-land, `%llu` becomes `%I64u` and `%zu` becomes `%Iu`.

i ended up using the following in my lab's codebase:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PRIuZ "Iu"
#else
#define PRIuZ "lu"
#endif
```

use:

```
printf("%"PRIuZ"\n", sizeof(struct foo));
```

i modeled the name from the definitions in C99's `inttypes.h`.

aside: my version of win64 mingw-gcc (4.4.5 20100527 (prerelease) [svn/rev.159909 - mingw-w64/oz]), plus `-Wall` or `-pedantic`, **always** warns when printing a `size_t`. it complains that `%I64u` and `%Iu` are nonstandard, and that `%lu` is incorrect. seems like the compiler is correctly getting tripped up by microsoft's insanity. i had to use `-pedantic -Wformat=0` to get it to not whine about `%Iu`.